# Estimating available RAM left with safety margin in C (STM32F4)

Tags: embedded, heap-memory, stm32, dynamic-memory-allocation, hal

I am currently developing application for STM32F407 using STM32CubeMx and Keil uVision. I know that dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems is mostly discouraged, but from spot to spot on internet I can find some arguments in favor of it.

Due to my inventors soul I wanted to try to do it, but do it safely. Let's assume I'm creating a dynamically allocated fifo for incoming UART messages, holding structs composed of the msg itself and its' length. However I wouldn't like to consume all the heap size doing so, therefore I want to check how much of it I have left: **Me new** (?) **idea is to try temporarily allocating some big chunk of memory** (say 100 char) **- if it's successful, I accept the incoming msg, if not - it means that I'm running out of heap and ignore the msg** (or accept it and dequeue the oldest). After checking I of course free the temp memory.

A few questions arise in my mind:

1. First of all, does it make sens at all? Do you think, basic on your experience, that it could be usefull and **safe**?
2. I couldn't find precise info about what exactly shares RAM in ES (I know about heap, stack and volatile vars) so my question is: providing that answer to 1. isn't "hell no go home", what size of the *temp memory checker* would you pick for the mentioned controller?
3. About the micro itself - it has 192kB RAM, however in the *Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32F4xx\Source\Templates\arm\startup_stm32f407xx.s* file only 512B+1024B are allocated for heap and stack - isn't that very little, leaving the whooping, remaining 190kB for volatile vars? Would augmenting the heap size to, say 50kB be sensible? If yes, do I do it directly in this file or it's a better practice to do it somewhere else?

Probably for some of you "safe dynamic memory" and "embedded" in one post is both schocking and dazzling, but keep in mind that this is experimenting and exploring new horizons :) Thanks and greetings.

Comment: If you want to safe RAM, you first might want to get rid of the ST "standard" library. This will not only free some RAM, but safe quite some code.

Comment: I use dynamic memory allocate on STM32F4 myself. However, I do use a pool, so I have RT/interrupt safe behaviour. However, I handle out-of-memory conditions appropriately.

Comment: @Olaf: I disagree with your stance on ST's StdPeriph lib.  I've had no problems with it.  Their Cube lib, on the other hand, is a pile of steaming horse crap.

Comment: @jalooc: If you're going to try and learn about dynamic memory allocation on embedded, you may as well start with some existing sources: http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Malloc-Free-Dynamic-Memory-Allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keil uVision describes only the IDE.  If you are using KEil MDK-ARM which implies ARM's RealView compiler then you can get accurate heap information using the [`__heapstats()` function](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0171b/Cihhgjad.html).

`__heapstats()` is a little strange in that rather than simply returning a value it outputs heap information to a formatted output stream facilitated by a function pointer and file descriptor passed to it.  The output function must have an `fprintf()` like interface.  You can use `fprintf()` of course, but that requires that you have correctly [retargetted the stdio](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm)

For example the following:

```
typedef int (*__heapprt)(void *, char const *, ...);
__heapstats( (__heapprt)fprintf, stdout ) ;
```

outputs for example:

```
4180 bytes in 1 free blocks (avge size 4180)
1 blocks 2^11+1 to 2^12
```

Unfortunately that does not really achieve what you need since it outputs text.  You could however implement your own function to capture the data in memory and parse the result. You may only need to capture the first decimal digit characters and discard anything else, except that the amount of free memory and the largest allocatable block are not necessarily the same thing of course.  Fragmentation is indicated by the number or free blocks and their average size.  You can perhaps guarantee to be able to allocate at least an average sized block.

The issue with dynamic allocation in embedded systems are to do with handling memory exhaustion and, in real-time systems, the non-deterministic timing of both allocation and deallocation using the default malloc/free implementations.  In your case you might be better off using a fixed-block allocator.  You can implement such an allocator by creating a static array of memory blocks (or by dynamically allocating them from the heap at start-up), and placing a pointer to each block on a queue or linked list or stack structure.  To allocate you simply remove a pointer from the queue/list/stack, and to free you place a pointer back.  When the available blocks structure is empty, memory is exhausted.  It is entirely deterministic, and because it is *your* implementation can be easily monitored for performance and capacity.

With respect to question 3.  You are expected to adjust the heap and system stack size to suit your application. Most tools I have used have a linker script that automatically allocates all available memory not statically allocated, allocated to a stack or reserved for other purposes to the heap.  However MDK-ARM does not do that in the default linker scripts but rather allocates a fixed size heap.

You can use the linker map file summary to determine how much space is unused and manually expand the heap.  I usually do that leaving a small amount of unused space to account for maintenance when the amount of statically allocated data may increase.  At some point however; you end up running out of memory, and the arcane error messages from the linker may not make it obvious that your heap is just too big.  It is possible to override the default linker script and provide your own, and no doubt possible then to automatically size the heap - though I have never taken the trouble to try it.

Comment: I still insist pool-based allocators are dynamic. I see the difference more between split/merge allocators and pool-like. Apart from that, I agree.

Comment: @Olaf : Yes they are dynamic in the sense that the memory blocks are assigned a purpose at runtime.  I don't think I have suggested otherwise. The point here is not to avoid dynamic memory allocation, but rather to avoid the non-deterministic behaviour of the default heap implementation.

Comment: I very well can live with that :-) (briefly: I agree)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have tested my idea with dynamic heap free space checking and it worked well (although I didn't perform long-run tests), however @Clifford answer and [this article](http://mil-embedded.com/articles/justifiably-apis-militaryaerospace-embedded-code/) convinced me to abandon the idea of dynamic allocation. Eventually I implemented my own, static heap with pages (2d array), occupied pages indicator (0-1 array of size of number of pages) and fifo of structs consisting of pointer to the msg on my static heap (actually just the index of the array) and length of message (to determine how many contiguous pages it occupies). 95% of msg I receive should take up only one page,  5% - 2 or 3 pages, so fragmentation is still possible, but at least I keep a tight rein on it and it affects only the part of memory assigned to this module of the code (in other words: the fragmentation doesn't leak to other parts of the code). So far it has worked without any problems and for sure is faster because the lookup time is O(n*m), n - number of pages, m - the longest page possible, but taking into consideration the laws of probability it goes down to O(n). Moreover n is always a lot smaller the number of all allocation units in memory, so way less to look for.

Comment: Well done for reporting your solution.  The advantage of your own implementation is you can then implement your own tools for performance analysis and  and tuning.